# Is it possible to cascade Wiki pages in Tiki?

Tags: cascade, tiki-wiki

I'm documenting objects in Tiki and would like to cascade all the descendants objects (Wiki pages) at the end of the current Wiki page.

So far I have only seen how to create a link to Wiki pages, but I want to embed the full wiki page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cascade wiki pages in Tiki using the Structures feature. See http://doc.tiki.org/Structures

To display the Table of Contents of the structure you can use {toc} syntax.

To "embed" full wiki page into another one, you can use the INCLUDE wikiplugin: http://doc.tiki.org/PluginInclude

Comment: Works as a charm! :) I have another question regarding Tiki, but I will make a new post.